# Publish web service - not found

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

I need publish some web services so I add some pages and codeunits to web services form. Then, I clicked publish checkbox to make it visible for my external program. When I try to visit

```
http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Services
```

it doesn't show my codeunits or pages avaliable. The only exists is SystemService. It doesn't work also when I try to reach it by

```
http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/<companyname>/Page/<wsname>
```

Message printed claim that "/Page/" was not found. I don't really know where could be problem and I feel I don't have enough knowledge about Dynamics solution to solve it. Maybe someone of you meet this problem in the past. I don't even know, where to search errors, where logs from publishing should be written. My version of this software is 2009.

Comment: Do you have a webserver running on localhost on port 7047?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I am able to see http://localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Services server response so I think yes.

Comment: Can we confirm the address that you're connecting to the RTC client to? It should be http://localhost/DynamicsNAV/ or similar. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you try pasting the url without the companyname? /DynamicsNAV/WS/Page/<wsname> in the way that is shown in localhost:7047/DynamicsNAV/WS/Services

Comment: It seems like no one mentioned that you could search for errors in [Event Viewer](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/226084-event-viewer-open-use-windows-7-a.html) on your server (where web service is installed).

Answer (score 0):

Could it perhaps be that you have multiple NAV service tiers running on your machine, and the one in which you are configuring your webservices is not the one listening to port 7047? Just trying to eliminate any possible cause... ;)

Answer (score 0):

More simple checks, just to be sure:

- is this the right database? :)
- have you specified service name (Latin characters, no spaces etc)?
- have you tried restarting NAV Server and Web Services?
- are published objects available in the license uploaded to DB?
- have you tried publishing standard page like 21 Customer Card?

(Sorry, this is not an answer, but there is no formatting in the comments :)